# Библиотека изображения wodpress и плагин polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Установлен плагин polylang картинки грузятся на английский язык и если переключится на турецкий библиотека изображений пустая.
Как сделать что бы в турецком в библиотеке изображений показывались те же картинки что и на английской?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно отключить данную настройку: Языки > Настройки > Медиафайлы.